# How to allow devices in Ufw Firewall for KDE Connect

Tags: networking, ufw, kde-connect

I am trying to connect my laptop with my mobile with **KDE Connect**. They both **didn't find any devices**...
Then after some google search, I found out that if we have enabled firewall(in my case, ufw) then **we have to allow our devices so that KDE Connect can work**. After a bit more google search I found out some commands that can be use to allow devices, but the problem is that I don't know anything about ip-addresses, or how to look for the devices connected to same network.
so please kindly help me...
*Kubuntu 22.04*

Comment: Welcome to AU. To be honest, I think you're asking in the wrong place - looks like you need a tutorial on networking / IP addresses? Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late,  but...
gufw is an GUI for ufw and it has the kde connect profile built in, so you can go to add rule > search for kde connect and that's it